# tracing specifec zipped Observable error when using Rxjava zip operator

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

if I have a case where I use Rxjava zip operator, let's say that it zip 4 different network calls.
for example:

```
Observable.zip(networkCall1, networkCall2, networkCall3, networkCall4),
(model1, model2, model3, model4) ->
Mapper.getResult(model1, model2, model3, model4)).subscribe(result -> {
//do some work
});
```

now if the error handling depends on knowing which Observable that cause this error, how could I know the specific Observable which throw the error. is there any Rx way to know such thing without breaking the stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To know which observable caused the error, you will need to annotate each observable.

```
Observable.zip(
 networkCall1
   .onErrorResumeNext( error -> Observable.error( new IllegalStateException( "stream1", error) ) ),
 networkCall2
   .onErrorResumeNext( error -> Observable.error( new IllegalStateException( "stream2", error) ) ),
 networkCall3
   .onErrorResumeNext( error -> Observable.error( new IllegalStateException( "stream3", error ) ) ),
 networkCall4
   .onErrorResumeNext( error -> Observable.error( new IllegalStateException( "stream4", error ) ) ) ),
(model1, model2, model3, model4) ->
Mapper.getResult(model1, model2, model3, model4)).subscribe(result -> {
//do some work
});
```

Then, in your error handler, handle the `IllegalStateException`, unwrapping the stream name and the original error.

Comment: this is a good answer, thanks ... waiting for any other suggestion